# Smart separators between self-hiding views

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that encapsulates some presentation logic, and as part of that logic, it can hide itself. A toy example:

```swift
struct Item: View {
    var x: Int

    var body: some View {
        if x % 3 == 1 {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
        return AnyView(Text("\(x)").background(Color.blue))
    }
}
```

When I'm using my `Item`'s in a `VStack`, it is smart enough to insert spacing only between non-empty ones.

```swift
VStack(spacing: 8) {
    Item(x: 0)
    Item(x: 1)
    Item(x: 2)
    Item(x: 3)
}
```

[image: Spacing]

Now I want to do the same, but using a custom separator instead of spacing. Similarly, I want separator to be inserted only between non-empty items.

[image: Separator]

Is there an API that would insert 2 separators between 3 visible views? Something like this:

```swift
Something(separator: Divider()) {
    Item(x: 0)
    Item(x: 1)
    Item(x: 2)
    Item(x: 3)
}
```

I've checked `VStack`, `Group`, `ForEach` but didn't find anything. I really don't want to lift the hiding logic up into the parent. Any ideas for the workaround that would keep the hiding logic inside the `Item`?

Comment: Then you need to put separator down into Item logic, because in general for container it does not matter which view to place it (Divider is just a view). So you need to keep somewhere a logic about separator either in parent or in child. (If you put empty view in List, you'll got just empty row with separator).

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach (and you continue use same `VStack`)

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct Item: View {
    var x: Int

    var body: some View {
        if x % 3 == 1 {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
        return AnyView(
            VStack {
                Text("\(x)").background(Color.blue)
                Divider().padding(.horizontal)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I want dividers only **between** the texts, the last one should not be there

Comment: I think adding condition to exclude last item is not so big deal for software engineer ;)